# Capistrano commands for creating database

Tags: capistrano

I'm trying to use capistrano commands to create a database. I only found a command like `deploy:migrate`. Is there a command for `db:create`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Capistrano doesn't provide any [recipes](http://capitate.rubyforge.org/recipes/deploy.html) for creating the database. As mentioned in this [capistrano googlegroups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/capistrano/a9ukNw8VAAM):

> it's not something that is generic enough to warrant inclusion in the
>   core, and it really falls under the domain of "administration" which
>   we try to avoid

Others have succeeded in automating the creation of database via capistrano by directly invoking the database creation command from the script.

The same thread mentioned above provides a [link to a capistrano script](https://gist.github.com/527117) which creates a mysql database by running the `mysql` command from capistrano.

Here is another useful blogpost: [Create MySQL database with Capistrano](http://www.grahambrooks.com/development/software%20development/2011/01/24/create-mysql-database-with-capistrano.html)

Comment: That's odd because it seems like `bundle exec rake db:create` is pretty generic. Would be like `cap deploy:setup`. Although I understand Lee's argument of having your server configuration handle this, many of use (for better or worse) use capistrano for server setup.

Comment: Yeah, this makes some sense. But, I'd like to be able to completely blow away my VM for staging, and recreate it from scratch at any point. I would also like to know that I can do this for production, though I probably never will. So, it seems like a commonly useful thing in that context.

Comment: I don't understand how migrating is common enough to warrant inclusion, but the initial DB creation is not.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier it seems like this recipe should be in https://github.com/capistrano/rails but it's not :(

Comment: bundle exec rake db:create does not create the database connection, it only creates the tables.    So the analogy @jwadsack is incorrect.

Comment: @mcr That's not my experience. If you run `rake --tasks` it says, "rake db:create # Create the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml for the current Rails.env (use db:create:all to create all dbs in the config)". To create tables I use `rake db:schema:load`.

Comment: I guess for me, "create the database", means, in postgresql terms, "createdb", which your web application users should never have permission to do.

Comment: Let's think about this for a moment: you can't deploy without a database created but rails, not a db admin, should create the database with `bundle exec rake db:create` but you can't run that till the site is deployed. Makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @prakash above, capistrano doesn't really provide any recipes for doing rake tasks to create a database. However, there is a capistrano add on gem that makes the process seamlessly painless.

On your gemfile, add

```
    gem 'capistrano-rails-collection'
```

Do a bundle install after that and then require it in your capfile like so

```
   require 'capistrano/rails/collection'
```

Now you can run rake tasks to create databases like so

```
   cap production rails:rake:db:reset
   cap production rails:rake:db:seed
```